How do I set a bookmarklet?
I am using a Chromebook. I am using a kids account. I need to bookmarklet infinite craft wiki and infinite craft.
I bookmarked them, but I don't know how to bookmarklet, it says I need to bookmarklet them.

A bookmarklet is a bit of JS saved as a bookmark. You don't bookmarklet a website. You bookmark a bookmarklet for use on a website. Even that may not work on the modern web - I've not used one in years, but the wikipedia article on the subject indicates content security policies might have broken it in many environments


Make sure the Bookmarks bar is visible

Select More   Bookmarks and lists  Show bookmarks bar.


Navigate to https://expitau.com/InfiniteCraftWiki/
Open 'Import User Data' by clicking on it in the top right-hand corner of the page.
Drag the green 'Sync with Wiki' button onto the Bookmarks bar. Now you've created the bookmarklet. It's called that because there's JavaScript behind it, not a https://... URL.
Navigate to https://neal.fun/infinite-craft/. Craft something simple.
Click on the bookmarklet
Allow pop-ups for neal.fun
Click the bookmarklet again. The Infinite Craft Wiki will open, showing items that have not yet been crafted with little red triangles in the top right corner.



Erratum: To allow pop-ups, you must select Always allow pop-ups and redirects from
https://neaLfun, not Continue blocking as in the .gif
